# Text recognition failed for different languages other than english [firebase ml vision]

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to recognize text from images. I am using the on device API for text recognition from the package [`firebase_ml_vision`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision).

My code snippets are given below:

```
                                          onTap: () async {
                                            final String recognizedText =
                                                await _initializeVision(
                                                    File(separateList[index]));
                                            Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) =>
                                                        TextRecognition(
                                                            recognizedText)));
                                          },
```

```
Future<String> _initializeVision(File image) async {
    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(image);

    final TextRecognizer textRecognizer =
        FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();

    final VisionText visionText =
        await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

    String text = "";
    for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        _textLines.add(line);
        text += line.text + '\n';
      }
    }
    return text;
  }
```

The code works fine when the text in the image is available in english language but it doesn't work for other languages such as Hindi, Russian etc.

Am i doing something wrong or it's the limitation of on device API?

Answer (score 0):

On-device recognition only supports latin languages, unfortunately.
If you want to detect other languages - you have to use the cloud-based recognition.